# compose navigation not getting the correct graph

Tags: android, navigation, android-jetpack-compose

i have nested navigation graph one for auth and another is the main after user logged-in .
now in main navigation if i want to navigate to a screen of the second graph it always search in the  first graph (auth ) .

my main activity

```
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            NotificationPermission()
            CompositionLocalProvider(LocalLayoutDirection provides LayoutDirection.Rtl) {
                Theme(darkTheme = false) {
                    ProvideWindowInsets(windowInsetsAnimationsEnabled = true) {
                        Navigation()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

here is my navigation code

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterialApi::class)
@Composable
fun Navigation(
    instantSessionViewModel: InstantSessionViewModel = hiltViewModel(),
    context: Context = LocalContext.current,
    activity: Activity = context.findActivity(),
) {
    val navController = rememberNavController()

    LaunchedEffect(key1 = true) {

//        here is my example to navigate to screen of my main graph
        delay(5.seconds)
            navController.navigate(
                Screen.example.route
            ) {
                popUpTo(Screen.MainScreen.route) {
                    inclusive = true
                }
            }
    }

  CompositionLocalProvider(LocalLayoutDirection provides LayoutDirection.Rtl) {

        NavHost(
            navController = navController,
            startDestination = Screen.AuthController.route
        ) {
            composable(route = Screen.AuthController.route) {
                AuthNavigation(navController)
            }
            composable(route = Screen.MainController.route) {
                MainNavigation(navController)
            }
        }
    }
}
```